# Are the elements of the set of adapted, almost surely increasing processes with $A_0=0$ finite variation processes?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

$\mathbb{A}_c=\{A_t \mid A \text{ adapted ,a.s continuous and increasing process,} A_0=0\}$

$\mathbb{V}_C=\{V_t \mid V \text{ adapted ,a.s continuous and finite variation  process,} V_0=0\}$

Is $\mathbb{A}_c \subseteq \mathbb{V}_c $?

Comment: A process is FV iff it is the difference of two nondecreasing processes.

Comment: @Calculon So we can write  $A \in \mathbb{A}_C$ as $A=A-0$ and since both $A$ and $0$ are non decreasing processes , A is finite variation. ?

Comment: That is right..